# Obtaining drop coordinates in react dnd

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I am looking to create a large drop target and find the drop coordinates. I know I can use `DropTargetMonitor` and `getClientOffset()` but I am not exactly sure of the right implementation. This is what I have so far:

I'm using the hook implementation:

```
const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: ItemTypes.Card,
    collect: monitor => ({
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver()
    )},
    drop: (item, monitor) => {
        const dropResult = ??
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, in the end my workaround is to put a div with element reference around the drop target and use that to measure. Because I also put other stuff inside that container div I position the drop target absolute over the entire container.

Something like this (pseudo-code, copy-paste at your own risk)

```
const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>();
const [, drop] = useDrop({
    drop: (item, monitor) => {
        console.log(
           containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect(), 
           monitor.getClientOffset())
        )
    }
    // etcetera
});
return (<div ref={containerRef} style={{postion:'relative'}}>
  <div ref={drop} style={{
     position:'absolute',top:0,left:0,width:'100%',height:'100%'
  }}></div>
</div>)
```